# EntityManager fails to instantiate using JPA/Hibernate when I add a OneToMany annotation

Tags: hibernate, scala, jpa, entitymanager

I have been struggling with not being able to have the EntityManager be instantiated when I add a `OneToMany` column to a class that already has a `OneToMany` column.

Right now the `EducationInfo` has a `OneToOne` to user, since each row will be unique to a person, but I want to be able to load all the education information given a username.

I am not changing the orm.xml file when I add the column, I just drop the database so it can be recreated.

```
class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(){val strategy = GenerationType.AUTO}
  var id : Int = _

  @Column{val nullable = false, val length=32}
  var firstName : String = ""
  var lastName : String = ""

  @Column{val nullable = false, val unique = true, val length = 30}
  var username : String = ""

  @OneToMany{val fetch = FetchType.EAGER, val cascade=Array(CascadeType.ALL)}
  var address : java.util.List[Address] = new java.util.ArrayList[Address]()

  @OneToMany{val fetch = FetchType.EAGER, val cascade=Array(CascadeType.ALL), val mappedBy="user"}
  var educationInfo : java.util.List[EducationInfo] = new java.util.ArrayList[EducationInfo]()
```

If I don't include the last column then my unit test works fine, but if I include this then all my unit tests fail.

Here is the class it is trying to use, and the unit tests for this class works fine:

```
@Entity
@Table{val name="educationinfo"}
class EducationInfo {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(){val strategy = GenerationType.AUTO}
  var id : Long = _

  @Column{val nullable = false, val length = 100}
  var name : String = "";

  @OneToOne{val fetch = FetchType.EAGER, val cascade = Array(CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE)}
  @JoinColumn{val name = "educationinfo_address_fk", val nullable = false}
  var location : Address = _

  @ManyToOne{val fetch = FetchType.LAZY, val cascade=Array(CascadeType.PERSIST)}
  @JoinColumn{val name = "educationinfo_user_fk", val nullable = false}
  var user : User = _

  @Column{val nullable = false, val length = 100}
  var degree : String = ""

  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  @Column{val nullable = true}
  var startyear : Date = new Date()
  var endyear : Date = new Date()

  @Column{val nullable = true, val length = 1000}
  var description : String = ""
}
```

**I am also curious if there is some way to know what the error is that prevents the EntityManager from being instantiated, but the main problem is what may be causing a problem when I add this column to User?**

**UPDATE:**

Removed a part that was in error.

**UPDATE 2:**

I changed the user column in the education entity to be `@ManyToOne` and all my unit tests failed.

The end of my error log is this:

```
15035 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: pojo
15035 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
15047 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
[PersistenceUnit: jpaweb] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
[PersistenceUnit: jpaweb] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

Then EntityManager is null in every test, so it fails.

**UPDATE 3:**

The `Address` entity has no foreign keys to anything, as it is called from several entities.

Could this problem be caused by using Apache Derby as the database?

Unfortunately I don't get any error message. I run this from within maven, and though I delete the database each time I can't tell what it happening that is wrong.  The @ManyToOne from EducationInfo -> User doesn't cause any problems, but @OneToMany -> EducationInfo from User does.

**UPDATE 4:**

I added a mappedBy to the User entity as suggested. I had that in another column definition, as I have five definitions that won't work, and I believe they are all for the same reason, so I am just testing with one.  Unfortunately it still leads to the EntiyManagerFactory not being built so all the tests fail.

**FINAL UPDATE:**

The actual case was

> cannot simultaneously fetch multiple
>   bags

so I just removed the FetchType completely from EducationInfo and the problem went away.

Comment: Were you able to get the actual error / stack trace printed? The only thing that looks somewhat fishy here is `@OneToOne` from `EducationInfo` to `Address` but it shouldn't be a problem since it's mapped via FK. Does `Address` have any `@OneToOne` mappings? Getting Hibernate's error message to print is most important here, it'll show you where to look for error.

Comment: I wish I could get the stacktrace, but I don't see how to get it.

Comment: I just noticed (annotations look somewhat differently in Scala) that you don't have `mappedBy` set on @OneToMany. You should: `mappedBy="user"` - that would mean that association is maintained by `EducationInfo` table.

Comment: You really need to figure out how to get the error message printed - I'm suspecting at this point that this is caused by something else. Sorry, I can't be of much help with Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OneToMany`'s complement mapping on the other side of association is `ManyToOne`, it **cannot** be `OneToOne`. That's what's causing `EntityManager` to fail.

It works when you remove the last line from `User` because then you're only left with `OneToMany` to `Address` and, although not shown here, presumably `Address` doesn't have a `OneToOne` link to `User`.

I'm no Scala expert; in Java you normally get an error and a stack trace printed when `EntityManager` fails to initialize; error message is not always extremely descriptive but usually says what mapping it has a problem with. Perhaps you need to tweak your logging settings if you don't get that error.

I didn't quite understand your model:

> Basically, a user should be able to
>   have several addresses, so I expect it
>   will become a ManyToMany, but each use
>   can also have several instances of
>   education information, so the need for
>   ManyToOne.

That sounds like @OneToMany from `User` to `Address` to me and (if "use" meant "user") as @OneToMany from `User` to `EducationInfo`.

> Right now the EducationInfo has a
>   OneToOne to user, since each row will
>   be unique to a person, but I want to
>   be able to load all the education
>   information given a username.

That conflicts with above. Either you can have several `EducationInfo` per `User` or it's "unique to a person".

Comment: Address did have a OneToOne link, but I realized an address could be shared.

Thank you for noticing the typo. 

I will make the change and see what happens.

Comment: It's still the OneToOne on User in EducationInfo.  That still needs to be ManyToOne

Comment: I updated my answer changed to @ManyToOne and it still fails.

Comment: I accepted your answer, you were an incredible help, and the solution isn't something I was expecting.

Comment: Thank you, I actually should have seen that. Scala-style annotations coupled with the fact that I myself never declare collections eager clouded my eyes :( On that topic, there's usually no reason to **always** eagerly fetch collections - and if you need to do it within a specific method you can use 'join fetch' in HQL or override fetch mode if using Criteria.